# Is the same (aux + subject + verb + comp) as (verb + subject + comp)

Tags: word-order, questions, do-support

Hi everyone excuse me if my english may fail.

I try to search about the different question types in the simple tense.

but i see if i want to ask a question i use the form aux + subject + verb + comp like "Do you like this food". but in other cases only invert the subject and the verb like "Can you fell this" is the same or there are other rules

Is the same
"Can i take it" as "Do i can take it" ?

or maybe there are another rule that i didn't know

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Only the first auxiliary verb inverts in questions. _Can_ is an auxiliary verb. You don't need _do_ when there is an auxiliary verb already.

Comment: ok i get it i didn't know that can verb is considered as auxiliary verb thanks a lot

Comment: @JuanSebastian There are three groups of auxiliary verbs 1) *be* and auxiliary *have* 2) the **modal verbs**: *can, could, shall, should, will, would may, might* and *must* 3) *do*, which we only use when we need an auxiliary but there isn't one already there. [There are a few other members of the auxiliaries, but they've got trickier grammar and you don't need to worry about these yet: *dare, need, ought (to)*]